# initial setup for hippo CMS is frozen and ends with error message

Tags: maven, hippocms

i am trying to get started with Hippo CMS. According to the docs [Get started with Hippo](https://www.onehippo.org/trails/getting-started/hippo-essentialsgetting-started.html) everything worked so far. But at the last step where you have to run

> mvn -Pcargo.run (-Drepo.path=storage)

the installation process seems to be frozen and after at least 5 min finishes with this error message. No idea what to do, according to the docs [Hippo Prerequisites](https://www.onehippo.org/trails/getting-started/prerequisites.html) everything is correct set up so far (Java and Maven Version).

The error message is as follows:

```
[INFO] --- cargo-maven2-plugin:1.6.5:start (cargo-run) @ myhippoproject 
--- [INFO] [2.ContainerStartMojo] Resolved container artifact 
org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-core-container-tomcat:jar:1.6.5 for container 
tomcat8x [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Tomcat 8.x starting... [INFO] 
[stalledLocalDeployer] Deploying 
[/Users/Mangrove/Desktop/myhippoproject/cms/target/cms.war] to 
[/Users/Mangrove/Desktop/myhippoproject/target/tomcat8x/webapps]... 
[INFO] [stalledLocalDeployer] Deploying 
[/Users/Mangrove/Desktop/myhippoproject/site/target/site.war] to 
[/Users/Mangrove/Desktop/myhippoproject/target/tomcat8x/webapps]... 
[WARNING] [stalledLocalDeployer] The WAR contains a context.xml file 
which sets the path to [essentials], which means path set it the Cargo 
configuration will be ignored by Tomcat [INFO] [stalledLocalDeployer] 
Deploying 
 [/Users/Mangrove/Desktop/myhippoproject/essentials
/target/essentials.war] 
to [/Users/Mangrove/Desktop/myhippoproject/target/tomcat8x/webapps]... 
[INFO] [yer.DeployerWatchdog] Deployable 
[http://localhost:8080/cargocpc/index.html] failed to finish deploying 
within the timeout period [600000]. The Deployable state is thus 
unknown. [WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] 
 org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Deployable 
[http://localhost:8080/cargocpc/index.html] failed to finish deploying 
 within the timeout period [600000]. The Deployable state is thus 
unknown. [ERROR] Starting container 

 [org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.
 Tomcat8xInstalledLocalContainer@40f8f 
 5a8] failed, now stopping container [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 
 Tomcat 8.x is stopping... [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Tomcat 8.x is 
 stopped [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------- 
 ----------------- [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO] ------------------------ 
 ------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 
 10:28 min [INFO] Finished at: 2018-05-13T15:57:13+02:00 [INFO] ------- 
 ----------------------------------------------------------------- 
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2- 
plugin:1.6.5:start (cargo-run) on project myhippoproject: Cannot start 
container 

 [org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.
Tomcat8xInstalledLocalContainer@40f8f 
5a8]: Deployable [http://localhost:8080/cargocpc/index.html] failed to 
finish deploying within the timeout period [600000]. The Deployable 
state is thus unknown. -> [Help 1] [ERROR] [ERROR] To see the full 
stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re- 
run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. [ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, 
please read the following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1] 
http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Any hint, advice, tipp, suggestion is very welcome, thanks.

Comment: Re-run, as maven suggests, with -e to see the stacktrace, or -X to see full debug if the stacktrace is not helpful (post it with the question anyway)

Comment: @guido stacktrace seems reapting it self with this message:     
                                                                                                     
[DEBUG] [URLDeployableMonitor] URL [http://localhost:8080/cargocpc/index.html] is not responding: -1 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
[DEBUG] [URLDeployableMonitor] Notifying monitor listener [org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.deployer.DeployerWatchdog@468be356]
[DEBUG] [URLDeployableMonitor] Checking URL [http://localhost:8080/cargocpc/index.html] for status using a timeout of [600000] ms... timeout isnt new :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i solved it. The Maven setup was not correctly wired. In any case i had to reset my pc, and suddenly it works now. Also i had different java versions at the time. Great help was also the hippo forum [Hippo Community Forum.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/hippo-community) Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

The error just means that the container did not start. The connection refused in this case is just a symptom of how cargo checks if the container is up.

That being said, this is quite a long time to have to wait to start. You could try to increase the timeout, but even this timeout is too long for regular work purposes.

Things to try include increasing the timeout, increasing jvm memory, start over, or try a different computer. Also make sure the process is running with the right permissions.

Comment: thanks for your help, i ll try with the process permissions,                     my feeling is ,its somewhere there, wow not so easy with the hippo :-)